# Get first order derivative from second order derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, euler-lagrange-equation

I am given:

$$ y'' = 11-y $$

$$y(2)=1 ; y'(2)=-4$$

and asked to use Euler's method to find $y(2.2)$ for $h=0.1$

To find $y'$ I simply took the integral of $y''$ to get:

$$y'=11x-yx$$

However, this does not satisfy the condition given above, that $y'(2)=-4$. Is this not the correct way of obtaining the first order derivative?

Comment: No, $y$ is not a constant, it is a function, it is $$y(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

The first-order system for your second-order equation is simply
\begin{align}
y'&=v,\\
v'&=11-y,
\end{align}
and the first Euler step correspondingly
\begin{align}
y_1&=y_0+hv_0,\\
v_1&=v_0+h(11-y_0).
\end{align}